# Azure redhat openshift creation via portal failing

Tags: azure, openshift, redhat, azure-service-principal

I am trying to deploy azure redhat openshift cluster from azure portal but it getting failed during validation Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'aadObjectId' at line '248' and column '24' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)"

Can any one suggest what to do here?

#azure
#azure redhat openshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you missed including `aadObjectId` parameter value while deploying the template.

I tried to deploy **Azure Red hat OpenShift cluster** custom template **without** including `aadObjectId` parameter value like below:

[image]

After selecting **Create** option, validation failed with below error:

[image]

When I checked **Basics** tab, it's saying *"The value must not be empty"* for  `aadObjectId`  like below:

[image]

When I opened the same template file in Visual Studio Code, I got **similar error** as you like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to include `aadObjectId` parameter value.

You can find the **value** of `aadObjectId` parameter like this:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your Service principal -> Overview***

[image]

After including  `aadObjectId` parameter value, **Validation passed** successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to include `aadObjectId` parameter value.

**Reference:**
[Deploy an Azure Red Hat OpenShift cluster with an ARM template | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/quickstart-openshift-arm-bicep-template?pivots=aro-arm#azuredeployjson-parameters)

Comment: i can't see the images you put for references

Comment: Could you check whether you can access `imgur.com` website or not? If that website is blocked by your company server/firewall, you may not see the images.

Comment: Yes i can see from my mobile now. Can you please let me know how get this custom template for this deployment.

Comment: I saved the template from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/quickstart-openshift-arm-bicep-template?pivots=aro-arm#create-an-arm-template:~:text=Save%20the%20following%20example%20as%20azuredeploy.json:) in **`azuredeploy.json`** file. Now,  *Go to Azure Portal -> Search for "Deploy from a custom template" and Click it-> Select "Build your own template in Editor"* like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5YgyIxB.png) and upload json file in Portal like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5q4hm6X.png). Make sure to add **required parameters**.

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi as for me access is limited to do this deployment so at the end it fails. Thanks for your help